# Explanation for N-queen with O(n) time complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, n-queens

I've run the implementation at available at:  http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/NQueens.java , which solve the N-queen problem with O(n) time complexity. It's amazingly fast and helps find out one solution without searching. However, I'm not really clear about the logic behind. 
Why do they split the problem into 3: odd, even (but not in form 6k), even (but not in form 6k+2).
Can any one check the code and explain in more detail for me (logic only)?

Comment: You need to ask a specific question...

Comment: It looks like a loop that just populates the array with a known answer. The author could of just populated the answer directly in O(1)

Answer (score 0):

They split the problem because neither construction covers all cases. Probably if you try to prove that they work in the bad cases, you'll find that a certain number is not a [unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_%28ring_theory%29) modulo n. This is a pretty typical state of affairs when constructing constrained combinatorial objects. For example, there exist [Steiner triple systems](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerTripleSystem.html) of orders 6k+1 and 6k+3, but the two residues mod 6 require different constructions.